# What is the equivalent data type for float* (image type) when importing a c++ dll into vb.net?

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, interop, type-conversion

I am trying to create a dll export function, in c++, to be imported from VB.NET.

i have created the function, but i don't know what is the argument type equivalent, to be used in calling.

in c++:

```
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL myFunction( const float *data, const char* filePath );
```

in vb.NET:

```
<DllImport("myDLL.dll", _
EntryPoint:="myFunction", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function myVBFunction( ByVal data As something, _ 
           ByVal filePath As String) As Boolean
End Function
```

Can somebody please tell me what to use for the `float *data` type (which would be an image format) and if i can use `String` to pass in the `filePath` - that will be received as `char*` - or what must i use instead ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `float` in C++ maps to the `Single` data type in VB.NET.

The `char*` for `filePath` should be a `String` in VB.NET.

Read [Data Types Compared in Different Languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xwz0t37%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, the float* type though... there are no pointers in VB ? I need to pass an image somehow...

Comment: VB.NET and .NET language as a whole do not really have pointers, because it is a managed memory run-time and the memory allocation is handled on your behalf. C# does allow for the concept of "unsafe" code that runs outside the confines of the .NET Framework and has the concept of pointers.

Comment: I think what you are really looking for is what was formerly called Managed C++, but is now referred to as C++/CLI. Read [C++/CLI Tutorial](http://www.asawicki.info/news_1472_ccli_tutorial.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, I will try using c++/CLI instead - but I still don't know what to use as data type for the image. Perhaps i can try a float/Single array and pass the address of the array ?

Comment: Not using C++/CLI, but using an IntPtr to the data - this is the actual answer